# Let $A = \{1,2\}$ and $R = \{(1,1)\}$. Is $R$ reflexive on $A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Assume we have $A = \{1,2\}$ Suppose $R$ is relation on $A$

**Case 1**

Let $R = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

I suppose in this case $R$ is reflexive.

**Case 2.**

Let $R = \{(1,1)\}$

Definition of the reflexive relation from the book:

> If $R$ is a relation on A and $\forall x \in A(xRx)$, then $R$ is
>   reflexive.

Looking at this definition, I believe that in case 2 $R$ is not reflexive, but I am not sure. Is it?

Comment: You are correct.  Probably they gave you this problem to check that you understand the symbol $\forall x$.  This is also an example to be given when students claim to prove: a relation that is symmetric and transitive must be reflexive.

Comment: @GEdgar, the reason why I'm asking this, is because initially I'd thought that the definition of the reflexive relation would be $\forall x \in A(x \in Dom(R) \implies xRx)$, so I just wanted to make sure that the definition given by the book is correct.